# Overlay Effect / Switching Effect on Bootstrap Cards Using Css or Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing a site's frontend in Bootstrap/Html/Css...Currently i am facing a small issue in css.I have created two cards using bootstrap cards and i am trying to apply Overlay effect or Flip effect on these two cards...I dont know what is the easiest way to apply this switching effect on two cards.

Any Help related to Css or Jquery would be highly appreciated.

**Here is my Bootstrap Code for Cards :**

```
               <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="today-special">
                    <h4>Today Special</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card card-one">
                              <img class="card-img-top" src="images/320x210.png" alt="Card image cap">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Pizza Marinara</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">80.96</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card card-two">
                              <img class="card-img-top" src="images/320x210.png" alt="Card image cap">
                              <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">Chicken Noodles</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">50.10</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                  </div>
              </div>
```

**CSS for the Cards :**

```
.today-special{
             text-align: left;

            .card-one{

                    width:14rem;
                    border: 1px solid #888888;
                    border-radius: unset;
                    box-shadow: 4px 5px 15px 1px #888888;

                    .card-text{

                            color: #FEA200;
                            font-weight: 500;
                    }
                }

            .card-two{

                    width:14rem;
                    border: 1px solid #888888;
                    border-radius: unset;
                    box-shadow: 4px 5px 15px 1px #888888;

                    .card-text{

                            color: #FEA200;
                            font-weight: 500;
                    }
                }    

            .card-img-top{

                border-radius: unset;
            }    
        }
```

**Currently My two bootstrap cards look like this :**

[image]

**I need these cards to look like this :**

[image]

Comment: It's really hard for us to help you without you posting your code

Comment: alright i am gonna edit this post and add the code...

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen.....code Added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add shadows to wrapper DIVs,
On `:hover` increment z-index the current `.card` and add shadow aswell

http://jsfiddle.net/31vrmjna/

```css
.card{

  &-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }

  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: unset;
  border: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;

  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    z-index: 2;
  }

  &-text{
    color: #FEA200;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  &-img-top{
    border-radius: unset;
  }  
}
```

```html
<link rel=stylesheet href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="today-special">
    <h4>Today Special</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 card-wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/320x210/0bf" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pizza Marinara</h5>
            <p class="card-text">80.96</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 card-wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="//placehold.it/320x210/f0b" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Chicken Noodles</h5>
            <p class="card-text">50.10</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```